# SMS Response Tracking in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

We are sending SMS through Mobile Connect,We would like to capture the exact response that the user has provided in Marketing Cloud,Is there a data store which stores the actual user response.

Thanks .

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure next keyword for that message (let's say REPLY) and then create new Text Response type SMS for that keyword. Using Ampscript in that new SMS you can capture customer response and store it in Data Extensison.

```
set @response = v([MSG(0)])
set @response = Replace(@response , 'REPLY ')
set @mobileNumber= MOBILE_NUMBER
InsertData('de_name', 'response', @response, 'number', @mobileNumber)
```

A note here - depending on mobile carrier your account was assigned, responses longer than 160 characters might get broken into multiple pieces, so whole message will be broken into multiple rows inside a Data Extension.

Comment: Thanks,This worked, the additional thing we are trying to capture now is the whole MSG array rather than the first word.Please let me know if you have any thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

There's a feature in MobileConnect meant exactly for this purpose. 
It's called `Info Capture` SMS template.

The way it works is you create custom, empty attribute in Mobileconnect Demographics table (for an example '**Input**') and then you can configure the template to use that attribute as the place to store customer provided SMS response.

Later you can query the MobileConnect Demographics table to get the content out.
You can also add AMPscript that it would automatically also create a row in some separate DE or even send it to Sales Cloud if needed.

Comment: Thanks ,will it work if we have a custom contact model?

Comment: Yes, the Mobile Demographics table is there for everyone and cannot be deleted/adjusted anyway, so no matter how custom model you have in general, these out-of-box solutions will always work.