# Insert response from a Journey Builder SMS into a blank data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, sms

Newbie question. I have journey with an SMS and I want to be able to record any recipient responses from that. The nature of the message doesn't prompt any action beyond replying STOP to unsubscribe, but I want to be able to record any other responses that may come through eg. Customer complaints etc.

I want to be able to record the response, SubscriberKey, and the mobile number into  a data extension into a new data extension. (The DE that is used for the entry source gets overwritten daily)

What AMPscript would I need to put in the SMS body?

Comment: You might find your answer here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/224736/sms-response-tracking-in-marketing-cloud